# Creating IMAP Connection using PHP

Tags: php, email, imap

I'm trying to create a script that will list emails in a mailbox with the end result being a cronjob setup to check the mailbox and save attachments depending on the subject contents - however I'm having trouble setting it up, could someone tell me where i'm going wrong or a more efficient way to establish a connection?

P.s I'm using 1and1 for my hosting.

CODE

```
<?php
$mbox = imap_open("{imap.ionos.co.uk:993}", "EMAILADDRESS", "ACCOUNTPASSWORD");

echo "<h1>Mailboxes</h1>\n";
$folders = imap_listmailbox($mbox, "{imap.ionos.co.uk:993}", "*");

if ($folders == false) {
    echo "Call failed<br />\n";
} else {
    foreach ($folders as $val) {
        echo $val . "<br />\n";
    }
}

echo "<h1>Headers in INBOX</h1>\n";
$headers = imap_headers($mbox);

if ($headers == false) {
    echo "Call failed<br />\n";
} else {
    foreach ($headers as $val) {
        echo $val . "<br />\n";
    }
}

imap_close($mbox);
?>
```

CURRENT OUTCOME
[image: Current Outcome]

Comment: This counts as a typo ... `$mbox instanceof IMAP\Connection` would have been `false` already.

Answer (score 1):

It turned out to be an easy fix, the mailbox uses SSL and my script didn't have anything for SSL. So I changed it to the below and it worked;

```
$mbox = imap_open ("{imap.ionos.co.uk:993/imap/ssl}INBOX", "EMAILADDRESS", "PASSWORD");
```

Answer (score -1):

You can use my class. I receive all e-mails from server and save into data base. I hope it will help.

Call method: bb_email_fetch() to start receiving.

https://github.com/BlazejPr/BKMailRecv/blob/main/BKMailRecv.php